# How to check whether xml element contain special word and than remove it (with c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I write in C# (asp.net) and make one xml file from many others, but in this files there are element (villageName) with text that I want to change. I want to check whether it contain "c." in the start and than I want to remove it.  The tag is repeated many times. Sometimes the value doesn't begin with "c."
 This is a part of my code.  Maybe here I must write the check.

```
 foreach (XmlElement singer in doc.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName("singers").Item(0).ChildNodes)
        {
            foreach (String element in elements)
            {

                XmlNodeList placeName = singer.GetElementsByTagName(element + "Place");

                XmlNodeList areaName = singer.GetElementsByTagName(element + "Area");
                if (villageName.Count != 0 && areaName.Count != 0)
                {
                villages.Add(new AddLocation(villageName.Item(0).InnerText, areaName.Item(0).InnerText));
                }
            }
        }



<singers>
    <singer>
        <sing>girls</sing>
        <gender>woman</gender>
        <livePlace>c. Vido </livePlace>
        <liveArea>Brabab</liveArea>
    </singer>
<singer>
        <sing>girls</sing>
        <gender>woman</gender>
        <livePlace>c. Ido </livePlace>
        <liveArea>Sab</liveArea>
    </singer>
<singer>
        <sing>girls</sing>
        <gender>woman</gender>
        <livePlace>Vido </livePlace>
        <liveArea>Brabab</liveArea>
    </singer>

</singers>
```

Comment: Please format your code so it is human readable. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to remove c. from the start of every element, or just one element with a particular name? Do you want to remove it from element names, element values or both? Please clarify your question.

Comment: I know your question is with Xml manipulation, but you could use a Regex replace.

Comment: You say "Sometimes the value doesn't begin with "c." Then what does it begin with? What are the possible values?

Answer (score 0):

This code should do the trick.  Where instead of using a node list you reference the root node of whatever you are trying to perform the replacement on.  Your code and question are a little unclear so I had to generalize it with the an XmlNodeList.

```
XmlNodeList nodeList = _xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("villageName");

            foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
            {
                if (node.InnerXml.Substring(0,1).Contains('c'))
                {
                    node.InnerXml.Remove(0, 1);
                }
            }
```